# How to allow http django heroku

Tags: django, heroku

I tried this

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    # SecurityMiddleware must be listed before other middleware
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    # ...
]

SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True
```

but still didn't change anything

I tried this package [django-sslify](https://pypi.org/project/django-sslify/) and added its middleware

```
MIDDLEWARE = [    
'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
'sslify.middleware.SSLifyMiddleware',
'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
```

but it gives me this error

```
TypeError: SSLifyMiddleware() takes no arguments
```

error traceback:

```
System check identified 2 issues (0 silenced).
January 31, 2021 - 09:14:56
Django version 3.1.5, using settings 'dashboard.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 954, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 892, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/hazem/.local/share/virtualenvs/dashboard-tUiBEpKo/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/hazem/.local/share/virtualenvs/dashboard-tUiBEpKo/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 138, in inner_run
    handler = self.get_handler(*args, **options)
  File "/home/hazem/.local/share/virtualenvs/dashboard-tUiBEpKo/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/runserver.py", line 27, in get_handler
    handler = super().get_handler(*args, **options)
  File "/home/hazem/.local/share/virtualenvs/dashboard-tUiBEpKo/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 65, in get_handler
    return get_internal_wsgi_application()
  File "/home/hazem/.local/share/virtualenvs/dashboard-tUiBEpKo/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 45, in get_internal_wsgi_application
    return import_string(app_path)
  File "/home/hazem/.local/share/virtualenvs/dashboard-tUiBEpKo/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 17, in import_string
    module = import_module(module_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 790, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/hazem/project/dashboard/dashboard/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
    application = get_wsgi_application()
  File "/home/hazem/.local/share/virtualenvs/dashboard-tUiBEpKo/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 13, in get_wsgi_application
    return WSGIHandler()
  File "/home/hazem/.local/share/virtualenvs/dashboard-tUiBEpKo/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 127, in __init__
    self.load_middleware()
  File "/home/hazem/.local/share/virtualenvs/dashboard-tUiBEpKo/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 58, in load_middleware
    mw_instance = middleware(adapted_handler)
TypeError: SSLifyMiddleware() takes no arguments
```

Comment: That package has not been updated in years, I don't imagine it's compatible with any current versions of Django/Python

Comment: I'm confused. Do you want to _permit_ HTTP requests or redirect them to HTTPS? Your question title and body seem to disagree.

Comment: @Chris I'm trying to permit HTTP or at least permit my api url only it's http not https

Comment: What do you mean by "permit my api url only it's http not https"? Are you using a custom domain, or a Heroku subdomain? What's stopping you from just using HTTP (though I strongly urge you to use HTTPS)?

Comment: My django application is deployed to heroku and the api is deplyed to aws ec2 as http when I try to send requests to it it gives me "Mixed content" error